# How do I check if a value a user is entering in Textbox is a numeric double?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to check if a user enters a number value in a textbox, decimal places accepted. Any help is highly appreciated.

```
Private Sub textbox1_AfterUpdate()
If IsNumeric(textbox1.Value) = False Then
Me!textbox1.Undo
    MsgBox "only numbers are allowed"
Exit Sub
End If
Exit Sub
```

using BeforeUpdate event:

```
Private Sub textbox1_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
If IsNumeric(textbox1.Value) = False Then
    MsgBox "only numbers are allowed"
Me!textbox1.Undo
Cancel = True
Exit Sub
End If
Exit Sub
```

My current code does not execute at all. I have also tried it in the textbox1_BeforeUpdate event. Please see code.

New Code:

```
Public Function IsValidKeyAscii(ByVal keyAscii As Integer, ByVal value As 
String) As Boolean
IsValidKeyAscii = (keyAscii = vbKeyDot And InStr(1, value, Chr$(vbKeyDot)) = 
0) Or (keyAscii >= vbKey0 And keyAscii <= vbKey9)
End Function

Private Sub textbox1_KeyDown(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
If Not IsValidKeyAscii(KeyCode, textbox1.value) Then KeyCode = 0

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't be using VBA for this task at all.

Just set the field format property to *General number*. That's the built-in way to ensure users can only enter numbers in a field.

Comment: Nice! I'm thinking I should probably avoid Access questions (or start fiddling with it)

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Please don't. Questions can have many answers, and yours might teach OP a valuable lesson about allowing only specific characters in a field. Mine just teaches OP to avoid VBA for simple input validation (Access has a lot of non-VBA features to validate input).

Comment: @Erik I did set the validation on the table but users have complained that there should be a way to undo the change. Currently they can only do so by using the Esc button but they usually have no idea what the Esc button is for.

Comment: @WKI If you have a formatting or validation rule on the field (like setting the format to _General Number_), that's very relevant information for the question. That would explain why your code wouldn't trigger, validation rules are evaluated before the `BeforeUpdate` event fires. You could consider removing the validation rule on the control, but not on the table, to allow your code to work.

Answer (score 2):

Write a validator function (could be in its own `KeyInputValidator` class or module), so you can reuse this logic everywhere you need it, instead of copy/pasting it for every numeric textbox you need:

```
Option Explicit
Private Const vbKeyDot As Integer = 46

'@Description("returns true if specified keyAscii is a number, or if it's a dot and value doesn't already contain one")
Public Function IsValidKeyAscii(ByVal keyAscii As Integer, ByVal value As String) As Boolean
    IsValidKeyAscii = (keyAscii = vbKeyDot And InStr(1, value, Chr$(vbKeyDot)) = 0) Or (keyAscii >= vbKey0 And keyAscii <= vbKey9)
End Function
```

Then use it in the textboxes' `KeyPress` event handler (assuming this is a `MSForms` textbox control) to determine whether or not to accept the input - since the event provides a `MSForms.ReturnInteger` object, that object's `Value` property can be set to `0` to "swallow" a keypress:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(ByVal keyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)
    If Not IsValidKeyAscii(keyAscii.Value, TextBox1.value) Then keyAscii.Value = 0
End Sub
```

That way you don't need to undo any inputs, or pop any annoying warning or message boxes: the value in the field is guaranteed to be a valid numeric value!

---

EDIT the above event handler signature is for a `MSForms` control. Looks like Access uses a different interface:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
```

Here the `KeyCode` is passed `ByRef`, so you can alter it directly. In other words, this becomes the logic:

```
    If Not IsValidKeyAscii(KeyCode, TextBox1.value) Then KeyCode = 0
```

Comment: Note: I'm not familiar with Access - [Erik's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54540115/1188513) should definitely be preferred in this case.

Comment: @Mathieus, I have tried your code but I get a error in line: "Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(ByVal keyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)" Do I need a any reference?

Comment: @WKI "assuming this is a MSForms textbox control" - looks like it's not the case then. I don't have MS-Access to test anything, but I can assure you that this code works flawlessly with a `UserForm`... I'm guessing you have an Access form, which seems to be using another type of controls. See if there's a `KeyDown` or `KeyPress` event that can be handled in a similar way.

Comment: @WKI a quick search showed that it appears the Access-forms textboxes *do* have a `KeyDown` event, just a different signature. See edit.

Comment: There is a KeyDown even Let me try and see!

Comment: I think I am getting there? Code added. Is there a way to enable the dotKey, Backkey, and EnterKey?

Comment: I don't think backspace or enter keys fire a `KeyDown` event (if they do then `vbKeyBack` (ascii 8) and `vbKeyReturn` (ascii 13) would do it). You might need a combination of `KeyDown` and `Change` handlers to handle these, and it gets rather complicated pretty fast. Note that the `vbKeyDot` (ascii 46) is manually declared here. Place a breakpoint (F9) in the event handler, see if the breakpoint is hit when you press such or such key, look at the value of the `KeyCode`, alter the procedure or validation logic accordingly.

Comment: I see. Thanks for helping me out.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the lost focus event:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_LostFocus()
    Dim blnNumber As Boolean
    Dim strNumber As String

    strNumber = TextBox1.Value
    blnNumber = IsNumeric(strNumber)

    If Not blnNumber Then
        Me!TextBox1.Undo
        MsgBox "only numbers are allowed"
    Else
        'And, if you want to force a decimal.
        If InStr(strNumber, ".") < 1 Then
            Me!TextBox1.Undo
            MsgBox "only doubles are allowed"
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Also, check the Textbox1 element that you have listed in access.  Is it's name TextBox1? or something else?
 For example, in excel it is represented like the following: `=EMBED("Forms.TextBox.1","")` even though the name that the code references is TextBox1.