# Validate input in unbound text control in MS Access, VBA

Tags: ms-access

Valid user input is of type integer. If user has mistyped for example 12e instead of 123 a message box should be displaying. I tried using validation with typename(mycontrol.text) function inside the before_update but didn't work.
Edit. The control refers to a linked table. The original table is in a MYSQL table and the field under consideration is of integer type.

Comment: The control refers to a linked table but is unbound (sounds wrong;) )? [`TextBox.Text`property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.textbox.text) always returns a string (and value wont help you too), but checking if a value is a number isn't too difficult (if it is ask web for "ms access vba check textbox value is a number")

Comment: @computerVersteher By unbound, I mean that the form in which the textbox resides is unbound. The controls in the form are populated by various linked tables. I have also tried using cint(), int() but in vain.

Comment: So textbox is unbound too! Result of asking the web as i suggested?

Comment: The functions cint() and int() that I mentioned were suggestions from the web.

Comment: First hit for  "ms access vba check textbox value is a number" on google is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54539560/how-do-i-check-if-a-value-a-user-is-entering-in-textbox-is-a-numeric-double for me and that contains serveral solution (use accepted but read others too)

Comment: I have an idea. First I will use isNumeric() to check if it is a number, and if yes then I will use int() to check if it is integer.

Comment: Use [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54540115/9439330)! Or feel the pain ;(

Answer (score 3):

By far the simplest way to do that is to assign a numeric format to the control.format (e.g: 'Standard').
This will *de facto* check that the entered value is numerical.
The trick works also with dates (using a date format of course) - much better than those tedious Input Masks I see too often.

Answer (score -1):

edit 09/12/2020. I got it! I used the functions IsNumeric(), Val() and Int(). This is my private function for validating the textbox named "TEKNA".

```
Private Sub TEKNA_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)

   If IsNumeric(TEKNA.Text) Then
        If Val(TEKNA.Text) = Int(TEKNA) Then
            'DO SOMETHING USEFUL
        Else
             MsgBox "You have to enter an  integer!"
             Cancel = True
        End If
   Else
        MsgBox "You have to enter an  integer!"
        Cancel = True
   End If

End Sub
```